# Problem during JBoss Launch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, networking, debian

I've a problem with JBoss 3.2.6. When I try to launch it, I get this error.

```
09:19:22,449 ERROR [StatefulSessionContainer] Starting failed jboss.j2ee:jndiName=TypicalBean,service=EJB
java.rmi.ServerException: Could not bind home; nested exception is: 
    javax.naming.CommunicationException: Network is unreachable [Root exception is java.io.IOException: Network is unreachable]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.ProxyFactory.bindProxy(ProxyFactory.java:385)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.ProxyFactory.start(ProxyFactory.java:187)
```

and so on ...

I use Java 1.6, and I can access to the Web, so I can't really figure out why this problem appears ...

Thanks (and sorry for my poor english)

Rob

Comment: JBoss 3.2.6? That's seriously old, is this a legacy system?

Comment: That's old, but I can't use another one due to some patches added on this version

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you're passing a "-b" or "--host" option referring to an IP that's not bound to any of your local interfaces.  I've had that happen a few times when copying installations between servers.

Comment: Nop. It's on a testing server, and there isn't any options like this in use. But perhaps, it's could be used for solving my issue... I'll look for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on linux OS, it might be a problem in your network configuration.
Check if yuors hostname stored in /etc/hostname is the same as the one in /etc/hosts which points to 127.0.0.1. I think I had similar problem, and I resolved it in this way.

Comment: The network configuration seems to be OK, especially this part.